# Expose SDRAM as a USB 3 mass storage device

Tags: microcontroller, usb, sdram

*Challenge:* 
Build a device that can host one or more SDRAMs (e.g DDR2, DDR3) and expose them as a USB 3 (slave) mass storage device.

Goal: 
Allow a USB 3 host to mount the device and allow near 5Gbit transfer rates.

*Attempt 1*:
Use a PC to build the device - fail - PC doesn't come with hardware necessary to use USB in slave mode.

*Attempt 2*:
Use a micro controller, such as PIC or ARM. SAM9 has support for DDR2, but lacks support for USB 3. Perhaps there're other micro controllers out there which would be suitable?

What other configurations can you think of that might help in solving the challenge?

*Note:* Please disregard the fact that SDRAM is volatile and somewhat unsuitable for storage.. Also, I'm aware of the existence of i-RAM or HyperDrive, which basically does the same thing but connected over PCI.

Comment: Isn't this called a thumb drive?

Comment: No, a thumb drive uses flash memories which are very slow (~20 MB/s). DDR SDRAM can reach over 30 gigabytes/s. So they're more than a thousand times faster :-)

Comment: Have you considered something like this: http://www.edn.com/article/517788-USB_3_0_controller_embeds_microcontroller_for_customized_applications.php

Comment: You won't get near 5Gbit transfer with a PIC.  This seems like FPGA territory to me.

Comment: I don't mean to hijack this thread, but does anyone make thunderbolt/lightpeak peripheral controllers yet?  For all out speed, this interface might help reduce your bottleneck over USB 3.0 since we're talking about RAM here.

Comment: Has anyone got an idea for how a PC could be exposed as a USB slave? Perhaps by using a PCI port? That could make a viable solution!

Comment: sounds like an interesting idea, specially if you got some spare ram lying around like small sodimm :)

Comment: @JonL I've registered with the thunderbolt people, but they aren't yet at the point where they're letting mere mortals get a hold of a spec, let alone hardware. :-(

Comment: I have heard that Firewire might be more suitable, in that it's easier to get a PC Firewire interface to operate as a slave.

Comment: reusing the northbdrige+the traces from an old motherboard could be an alternative,but they are probably difficult to interface...

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I can disregard the sanity of this project. It is insane, by the way, with little or no practical value beyond "doing it"-- but that never stopped me before and it shouldn't stop you.

In my opinion, you need several things:  A CPU, an FPGA, some SDRAM, and a USB interface.  Cypress makes the [EX USB FX3](http://www.cypress.com/?id=3526) that does 2 of the 4 things.  It has an ARM 9 CPU and USB 3.0 interface.  What it doesn't have is an SDRAM interface-- which is why you want an FPGA.  The FPGA does both the SDRAM interface as well as the high-speed data interface to the USB3 logic.

What you absolutely **do NOT want** is for the CPU to do the bulk of the data transfer!  A 100 MHz ARM 9 isn't going to be able to handle that kind of data throughput.  For that matter, just about any 2 GHz CPU isn't going to be able to handle that amount of data either.  The ARM9 is just there for the housekeeping, while the FPGA does the heavy-lifting.

The ideal FPGA for this project is a Xilinx Spartan-6.  Relatively low-cost, easy to program, and has built-in hard cores for the DDR2 SDRAM interface.

Comment: No practical use?  How about a scratch drive for something like Photoshop when you're working with huge images?  Or as an incredibly fast swap drive for Linux?  I want one of these!

Comment: @Majenko  <Facepalm>  Oh, where to start.  The best option for a fast scratch drive would be to install more SDRAM in your PC and run some software for a RAM-Disk.  That is the cheapest and fastest option.  Using RAM-Disk (USB or otherwise) as a swap-drive is just silly.  Add that same RAM to your PC's main memory so it doesn't have to swap at all!

Comment: @Majenko Or maybe I suffered from Poe's Law...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe's_law

Comment: And if you're at your limit?  And you have no option to replace the mobo (such as a laptop?)

Comment: @Majenko  In that case you have to ask yourself:  should I spend money to make the swap/scratch space faster, or would my money be better spent upgrading the entire computer?  A fast USB3.0 RAM-Disk will speed up Photoshop, but a new computer will speed up everything.  Keep in mind that today a USB3 RAM-Disk doesn't exist and will cost much more than US$2,000 to build (parts + labor + whatever).  This would be a much different issue if it cost $100, but it will never be that cheap.

Comment: Yes, but a new computer doesn't have the geek factor that a super-fast external ram disk would have.  And geek factor is important in a thing like this.

Comment: @DavidKessner Thanks for the answer! I might need to take a few courses to become knowledgeable enough for this kind of solution. As for value it is mainly that of curiosity and the creative aspect of following up on crazy ideas. However, I have a few practical areas in mind as well. One could for example run a OS booted from USB such as Ubuntu Live. This should make the system extremely fast. Another area of interest is to make a super-fast bridge between my Media Center and PC :-)

Comment: @Mika - Booting from a live CD already caches and buffers the information in RAM.  Or, again, copy the CD to a RAM disk on the PC, and run it from there.  That way, your CPU will avoid the overhead of translating everything to USB 3 (an overhead which you've thus far ignored) and directly access the memory (which has been noted already to be much faster). USB 3 has three differential pairs over which which you can push 5 gigabits/s, and requires protocol overhead.  A stick of DDR3 has 64 data pins plus addressing pins, and can hit 17 gigabytes/s, or 136 gigabits/s (27 times faster!)

Comment: @Majenko - Performance always trumps geek factor IMO.  Besides, having absurd amounts of RAM in your laptop or PC carries plenty of geek cred.